# Sorting algorithm without using compareTo

Tags: java

I'm working on a homework assignment that requires me to compare two strings and determine if they're in alphabetical order.

I plan to write a method that will take two strings as arguments, (String a, String b) and return either 1, 0, or -1 (so, an int) signalling whether a > b, a < b, or otherwise (the 0 case).

For example, comparing ("boogie", "orange") would return a -1. since, boogie < orange.

My code so far is

```
public static int compare(String a, String b) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < b.length(); j++) {
            char cha = a.charAt(i);
            char chb = b.charAt(j);
            if (cha < chb) {
                return -1;
            } else if (cha > chb) {
                return 1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

However, I am encountering numerous errors and cannot find fixes for the bugs. I'm also having difficulty finding a code for measuring if one word is longer than another (which affects alphabetical order) Can someone help me debug the code and point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're getting errors, **always** post them. Don't make us sit here and guess!

Comment: "I'm also having difficulty finding a code for measuring if one word is longer than another (which affects alphabetical order)" ...length()?

Comment: When you say alphabetical order between the two words what do you mean: the first letter of each word? All letters compared to each other? Right now you are only comparing first characters in each word because as soon as you have a match `cha > chb` or `cha < chb` it returns. It will also return 0 right now if both words are identical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a nestd loop, since you don't want to compare every character of one String to every character of the other String.

You only need a single loop:

```
public static int compare(String a, String b)
{
    int len = Math.min (a.length(),b.length());
    for (int i = 0; i<len; i++) {
        char cha = a.charAt(i);
        char chb = b.charAt(i);
        if (cha < chb) {
            return -1;
        } else if (cha > chb) {
            return 1; 
        }
    }
    if (a.length() < b.length())
        return -1;
    else if (a.length() > b.length())
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

As for handling Strings of different lengths, if you find that the shorter of the 2 Strings is equal to the prefix of the longer String, you return -1 if a is the shorter String and 1 if b is shorter (since the shorter String should come before the longer one).

Comment: can characters be compared by `<` or `>`?

Comment: @Apurva Characters have integer value between 0 and 2^16-1, so they can be compared with < or >.

Comment: Yes, in java you can compare character with <,>,<=,>=,== etc. just like Integers.

Comment: This code will only compare a part of whichever String is shorter, not the whole word. If we have 2 words one is 5 chars and another is 7 the first 5 chars in the longer word might be less than the smaller word, but can't it be that the full length of the larger word be larger than the short word?

Comment: Isn't it better to convert every character of a string into `ASCII` and then compare it as we do for `int`?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile; you're missing () for the lengths of a and b.

Comment: @CodeWhisperer Based on lexicographical order abcde < abcdexx (regardless of what characters appear in place of xx). The longer word would always be larger than the shorter word if the longer word starts with the shorter word.

Comment: @Aify Thanks. I got confused with .length of array. Fixed now.

Comment: Also, would it be more efficient to do a quick `.equals()` in the beginning of the function to return 0?

Comment: @Aify No, it wouldn't, since equals also iterates over the characters of the two Strings (assuming they have equal length), so you'll be running some of the logic twice.

Comment: Thank you for your response! So I'm getting the error of "length cannot be resolved or is not a field". I've initialized Strings a and b, but I don't understand why the length can't be resolved. Do I need to declare the strings in this method AND the main method?

Comment: I changed that too but then forgot to initialize the strings :P. Silly me. Coding is super frustrating sometimes.

Comment: I think I've fixed the code, but now I can't seem to make it print anything. shouldn't it just be System.out.println(compare("boogie", "orange")); ? Never mind, I missed a '('. The code runs correctly now. Thank you sir!

Answer (score -1):

You can compare two char by using '-' operator rather than the '>'.
For example below.

```
public static int compare(String a, String b) {
   return  a.charAt(0) - b.charAt(0);
}
```

In your case, something like this.

```
public static int compare(char cha, char chb) {
    if (cha-chb < 0) {
         return -1;
     } else if(chb - cha > 0){
         return 1;
     } else if(chb - cha == 0){
         return 0;
     }
    return 0;
}
```